# How do you set up TFS and a Test Controller on a Azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to get full access to the full functionality of Test Manager however I need a Test controller to do so.

We do not have a TFS on premise server so we have decided to try and set TFS and the Test controller up on a Azure Virtual Machine.

This is proving to be quite a tricky operation, does any know the steps that would be required to get this set up?

Comment: For Azure VMs the installation should not be any different from the doing the same on On-Premise, can you ask more specific question where exactly you're finding it difficult?

Comment: Do you want to use Visual Studio Online instead of running your own TFS server in an Azure IaaS machine?  If you really do want to manage your own TFS instance and hardware, there is a pre-built VM in the Azure VM Gallery that already has TFS installed.

Answer (score 2):

The process is pretty much identical to setting up TFS on-premise (install TFS from the TFS ISO, then install the Test Controller from the Agents ISO).

You can read the TFS install guide here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631902.aspx

Also the install instructions for a Test Controller are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd648127.aspx

Lastly the ALM Rangers wrote a guide specifically around deploying TFS to Azure IaaS VM's.  You can find that here: http://vsarplanningguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/122171